# Node.js: Find truncated image downloads

Tags: node.js

I have created an image downloader in node.js. However I did not handle the data event properly meaning that some of the images were truncated (leaving the remainder of the image filled with plain white, black or gray). I need to programmatically identify the truncated images in node.js so I can use my downloader to redownload them.

Here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7SoO.jpg) for an image that was truncated when downloading and its fully downloaded counterpart.

How can I programmatically identify images like this from a folder of ~700,000?

This is the script I previously used to download images. I am not sure how to correctly handle the data event to prevent the truncating of images.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra'); 
var progress = require('request-progress');
var probe = require('probe-image-size');
... 
downloadImage(url, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var req = request(url);
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirname)) fs.ensureDirSync(path.dirname(filename));
        var image;
        var bytes;
        var type;

        progress(req, { delay: 0 }).on('progress', function (state) {
            reportDownloadSpeed(status.speed);
        })
        .on('response', response => {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                type = mime.getExtension(response.headers['content-type']);
                filename = filename + '.' + type;
                image = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
                bytes = response.headers['content-length'];
                req.pipe(image);
            } else {
                reject(response.statusCode);
            }
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
            reject(error);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            image.close();
            var input = require('fs').createReadStream(filename);
            // Get the width and height
            probe(input).then(result => {
                input.destroy();
                if (result != null) {
                    resolve({
                        'bytes': bytes,
                        'width': result.width,
                        'height': result.height,
                        'type': type
                    });
                } else {
                    reject('Not an image or corrupt');
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

How do I prevent the truncating of images while downloading?

Comment: Could you cross-check the bytes read following the headers against the content-length?

Comment: I did not store the content-length in my database, only the size of the file on my disk. It would take months to recheck the content-length of every image url.

Comment: Ah.  I was more thinking about the answer to your question, _how do I prevent the truncating of images while downloading?_.  This would involve either counting the bytes downloaded (adding a `data` event handler, in addition to the `pipe` that counts bytes; or checking the size of the downloaded file).  As for the files already downloaded, perhaps graphicsmagick could help you verify the images in your db.

Comment: I've seen people recommend imagemagick before, but I don't have any idea where to start. How would I utilize image/graphicsmagick?